# Sending JSON output in __construct in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a quick question that has kept me busy for hours. I'm still learning Laravel and have a question about the __construct() function. Would it be possible to send a response from the __construct part?

**Example**

```php
public function __construct()
{
    $check = 1;
    if ($check == 1) {
        Response::json('error', 404);
    }
}
```

What would be the correct way to execute something like this?

Comment: You should never send response from constructor of controllers. Although you can redirect from constructors.

Comment: I just found that out, best way would be middleware to use.

Comment: middleware are only guards for controllers, they should be used only for preventing access to controller functions, nothing else. Once you use a middleware and it denies access to controller function, an error will be automatically thrown.

Comment: That was my end goal, to make a roles function, this works with middleware. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not recommended to use the constructor. 
Can use the middleware function in Laravel to get execute a function.